# Offensive flag rejected

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, offensive-flag

My "offensive" [flag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/119527) for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37648703/cannot-create-exe-file-using-py2exe) was rejected. It's not surprising, based on the question in its current form, but prior to the [edits](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37648703/revisions) (which occurred after my flag), the body of the question ended with

> byway,Choose Hanzo And Your Father Will Die.

A threat to my father is quite offensive.

Curious that I was missing some sort of pop culture reference (which would still be tacky, and make no sense in the context of the question), I [Googled for the phrase](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Choose+Hanzo+And+Your+Father+Will+Die%22) which leaves me even more confused, and wondering if this person desired for their account to be suspended.

Comment: Perhaps a custom flag would have been appropriate. It took me a while to find that phrase *even knowing what I was looking for*. Alternatively, it could have just been edited out

Comment: "Choose Hanzo And Your Father Will Die" appears to be a reference to a Blizzard game or something? https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4m5w5s/

Comment: @Rob The question, code excluded, was *two sentences*; that one being the only one with any capitalization. Also, I see editing out pure nonsense like that to be only scraping away the surface of the problem. IMO, anyone who wants to include bizarre, or other "inside joke"-like things that have the potential to be offensive in their questions doesn't belong on Stack Overflow. (FTR I wasn't *actually* offended, but this is just stupid).

Comment: On topic: This phrase is almost certainly a reference to an often reviled character in the recently released FPS video game by blizzard called overwatch.

Comment: "rainbowattack.png", hopefully they'll reverse the Great Firewall before he figures out the flaw in that approach.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart "I wasn't actually offended..."  If you weren't actually offended, why are you flagging it as offensive?

Comment: Sometimes edits cause legitimate flags to be declined. My one declined Abusive/Offensive flag was like this. It transformed from a page full of nonsense, to a question. It's deleted now, but you might be able to see [it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36832823) if you have enough rep.

Comment: @Laurel There was never anything offensive or abusive in that post, either. Even before being edited, it was just a terrible question with a bunch of Lorem ipsum filler text (which was a badly-formatted version of the webpage the OP was working on).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot According to [Shog](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234035), it was an appropriate use of the flag. "Lorem Ipsum" is not a question.

Comment: @Laurel No, it wasn't. The first version of the post contains a question (sort of): "I need to order the divs or panel in order 1,2,3,4,5,6..." Unless you flagged it during the grace period, there's no way that can be construed as abusive. I do find it offensively bad, but that doesn't justify a flag ;P

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I may have missed that then.

Comment: The question no longer exists, so this post is somewhat useless. In addition, the cached copy (I'm not saying where) shows that the user has lost reputation due to negative scoring. That in itself is a punishment. And like some of the answers below state, the flags are not intended for moderation of the site, not for tiny things that do not pertain to a single person, and are not valid threats (did you really believe he knew where your father lives and was going to take your father's life?)

Comment: It's really less of a threat and more of an inaccurate forecast based on a videogame in-joke. Dr DealWithIt prescribes not taking things on the internet so seriously. If the original poster of this Is guilty of anything, it's making a reference nobody got/thinks is funny.

Comment: @Logan I know. I really don't get my panties in a bunch over internet things. If there had been a "includes obnoxious content, give a warning to the OP less subtle than editing his question" flag, I would have used it.

Answer (score 127):

The offensive flag is for complete garbage that needs to be destroyed now. A validated offensive flag or 6 of these by users automatically delete and lock the question, and impose a -100 reputation penalty as well as large heuristic bias against the asker in question and answer bans.

It should only be used to posts that were clearly never intended to be a constructive question, and not for posts where some inappropiate language is contained within, but there is also a question.

In these cases, you should simply edit the offensive language out and leave a comment reminding the user of the "be nice" policy.

When a user continues to be agressive and/or inappropiate after, you can raise a custom mod flag to explain your concerns.

TL;DR: **An offensive flag is a nuke, be careful with using it.**

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize the implications of the flag, and now realize it was inappropriate for the situation.

Comment: What is an "offensive" flag?  Do you mean "Rude or Abusive"?

Comment: Hm, nobody really knows this. Can we have a (red) confirmation popup with short summary of this info when using offensive flag?

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov That sounds like an awesome suggestion in and of itself.

Comment: I had no idea the offensive flag was so...intense. I've marked Oleg's comment as helpful, but I felt like chiming in, as well. Perhaps a FAQ question could be added about this, as well?

Comment: @JonHarper Next to the "Spam" flag, the other red flag, the offensive flag is one of the strongest signals you can give about a post. In fact, a new(ish) user who gets a post nuked by it will almost instantly incur an IP block.

Comment: @GreySage, filled as feature request: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/325673/936986

Comment: @J... "Rude or Abusive" is on comments, posts have an offensive flag option.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan It was a rhetorical question, and no they don't.  Go push the `flag` button and tell me where you see it.

Comment: @J... & SuperBiasedMan: "Rude or Offensive" is on comments, "Rude or Abusive" is on questions and answers.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I don't think comment flags carry the same rep penalty as Q/A flags, though... it's a different thing altogether.

Comment: @J...: I think you're right about that.

Answer (score 44):

This was obviously not intended as a personal insult. It wasn't even addressed to you, or to anyone present! It was not "offensive" (in so much as we can deem anything to be *objectively* so), but merely noise. You should not have cast an offensive flag, and it was correctly declined.

Apparently you already knew this, as I quote:

> I wasn't *actually* offended, but this is just stupid

so I don't really understand your surprise at the outcome.

Comment: My intention in raising the flag was to point out to someone that the user might have been using Stack Overflow as a channel for some activity other than programming questions. I considered the spam flag too, but that doesn't apply either. With the strangeness of it, I wasn't sure that the code was really even then point of the post. I wasn't being overly-sensitive, I'm just ever annoyed with the amount of garbage on SO, and I didn't think that just editing it out would suffice.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: Well we don't want garbage flags any more than we want garbage posts ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It's already a garbage flag if marking needlessly rude language as offensive isn't actually the intent of the flag. Maybe it shouldn't actually be named 'offensive' then, but something that indicates whatever it is supposed to be used for.

Comment: I don't accept the implication that you need to be personally offended. The criterion should be that a reasonable person would find it offensive by prevailing community standards.

Comment: I concur with @EJP. I get personally offended by almost nothing, it just doesn't phase me. But some people are, and there is a "common sense" definition of offensive at play here.

Comment: @EJP To avoid [groupthink](https://www.google.com/search?q=groupthink), if you're not personally offended, maybe let someone else flag it, who is?

Comment: @jib Waiting for someone to be offended before taking action is suboptimal.

Comment: @Oktalist depends what you're optimizing for. If we can't tell the people who are offended from those pretending to be offended, then how will we know anyone is offended?

Comment: Easy, assume everything is offensive to at least one person in the world. (Time to delete Stack Overflow...)

Comment: Don't assume that "offensive" is synonymous with "causes offence".

Comment: @Oktalist: Why not, when that's literally what it means?

Comment: If a tree says a racial slur in the forest and no-one's around to hear it, is it still offensive?

Comment: @Oktalist: That situation has undefined behaviour ;) In all seriousness, it's neither offensive nor offensive because it's up for debate whether the tree said anything at all.