# Add a red tooltip signaling that the "offensive" flag is a nuke

Tags: feature-request, flags, offensive-flag

[A recent answer to a question about a rejected offensive flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325546/936986) explained that an offensive flag is a real nuke that should be used only for posts that are completely made just to be offensive.

I didn't know that and I remember trying to use this flag for a pretty insignificant reason, compared to the punishment it would deliver. I also didn't knew that it could be resolved automatically if 6 users used it.

Since this seems to be a tool that should be reserved for extreme cases, can we please have a highly visible (e.g. red) tooltip with a short summary about this information when a user selects this flag?

My comment on the linked answer about this issue is already at 45+, so I guess people are in favor of this idea.

Comment: And possibly one for spam too. Many people take it to mean repetitive and low-quality (as spam usually fits both of those criteria), but it should not be used unless it is an unsolicited, irrelevant product endorsement.

Comment: Maybe we put a box around them and title it "Nuclear Weapons".

Comment: "Flags of Mass Distruction" ?

Comment: Spam spam spam spamity spam spam spam.  Spamity spam, spamity spaaaaam, spamity spam, spamity spaaaaaaaaaam.  (Using spam for automated mass-UCE came from its use as a word for repeteitive and tiresome content, so the misunderstanding is natural.)

Comment: ([Yakety @Yak](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-cHB3Rbz1OI)?)

Comment: This might fit in with other context-specific flag warnings that I'd suggested here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309732/provide-context-specific-warnings-at-time-of-flagging-for-incorrect-flag-use

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310551/correction-for-the-be-nice-page-in-the-help-center (not a duplicate; my suggestion was to add clarification to the Help Center page)

Comment: No one reads tooltips, and even if they did, this is a [Candy Machine Interface](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/08/high-maintenance/) if I've ever seen one. Either take the nuke off the launchpad if we don't actually expect people to use it, rename the option to what it actually does, or remove it altogether.

Comment: Always open to improving these UIs, but... Basing the need for improvement on someone who clearly didn't take the post he was flagging seriously doesn't seem like a great idea.

Answer (score 52):

I've never been completely happy with how we show these options in the flag dialog. For context, here they are (captured from here on Meta):

[image: Flag Dialog]

Someone with a trained UX eye can probably point out why I don't think they're optimal. They are, as you put it, nukes, and any context on how or when they should be used lives in a linked resource.

Folks aren't .. always the best at reading what's in front of them, much less a link that leads to entire *paragraphs* of stuff to read. Oh, the huge manatee!

[image: It's huge]

The problem lies in the explanation; we've got a mere *two* sentences before we lose any meaningful grip on the shorter of attention spans. This problem becomes very interesting for 'spam', because there are instances where affiliation is properly disclosed and the post is put forth in good faith.

What if we made this a little closer to the dialog that moderators see when they decide if an account *is* in fact worthy of a brief sojourn into ballistic exercises?

[image: The Big Red Blinking Button]

What this would translate to in the flag dialog is:

**spam**

> This is in no way an attempt to contribute a real, good-faith question or answer to the site; it's spam that discloses no affiliation and adds no value. This post should be removed from the site and the author should be subject to an administrative penalty, or possibly removed entirely.

**rude or abusive**

> This post is written with the express intent of insulting, belittling or intimidating specific individuals or groups of people. It should be immediately removed from the site and the author should subject to an administrative penalty or possibly removed entirely.

***I've considered it many, many times.***

The problems are:

- Even with the clearer explanation, folks will continue to flag stuff that they simply don't like as spam or offensive. Though, it's *pretty* rare that enough flags follow to launch missiles. A case to keep in mind, not really worth optimizing for.
- Making the penalty clearer adds friction, I'm worried that we'll actually cut the (very) efficient manner that the real spam / troll fodder is cleared.
- I worry that we'll sweep up more folks that are actually making a good-faith attempt at answering (even if they end up doing it wrong). *Oh, cool - that thing I just pushed to github would totally work for this person, I'll post a link to it.* - That's *not* an uncommon or irrational process, keep in mind that our standards are *way* higher than most and not always obvious.

I'm open, I'm happy to explore ideas. Between Shog, Bluefeet, Jon and myself - we've probably put at least two months of person hours into figuring out how to present those options better.

I like the copy that I came up with because it seems really clear to me, but I can't ignore the fact that I'm quite biased after being here for as long as I have. I'm willing to test something different, but I want to set everyone's expectations; I'm not sure if there *is* a good combination of words to put there.

Comment: We should definitely add that picture to the new flag dialog. :) It will make it clearer that wrongly using spam or offensive flags kills innocent flying sea mammals.

Comment: "removed entirely" sounds like an example of "administrative penalty." Not sure both need to be mentioned.

Comment: Just turn the background red for those two items in the screenshot.

Comment: I didn't realise that this type of flag would carry -100 if it is successful so "Administrative penalty" sells it for me. If I saw that I'm much more likely to read associated docs to find out whether this is justified in my opinion.

Comment: I actually find both of these more descriptive and all around better then the current ones, tim.

Comment: You can cut that final sentence further. Removal of the user is just a special type of administrative penalty, and not a choice that's going to be made by the flagger. So just say: *"It should be immediately removed from the site, and the author should be subject to an administrative penalty."* (for both of 'em). Or maybe even punchier: *"It should be immediately removed from the site, and the author should be penalized."* Who cares if it's "administrative"? What does that even mean to the average flagger? "Penalized" seems ominous enough to convey the message.

Comment: As for your "problems," I don't really follow the relevance. Sure, the clearer explanation won't solve all of the problems, but if it solves *some* of the confusion, that's still a net win. Clearly there are users who are confused about what the flags mean and what action will be taken as a result. For your second problem, where is the friction? How does making something clearer ever add friction? The only way I can see is the explanations are slightly longer, but that can be tweaked. Third, OK sure, but I still don't see how the new verbiage would make this problem *worse*.

Comment: In response to your "we're hitting legit users with spam flags" and your example about the current thing with github, its already happening now. Some people get trigger happy with the flag and leave a comment causing others to pile on. Maybe if the flag text talks about there being a harsh administrative penalty, some of these folks think twice before nuking someone who wanted to help. In any case, more so then right now.

Comment: The description of the flags themselves appear to be much less severe than the actual consequences. The descriptions imply this is a simple "this does not belong here" flag, but thanks to Meta, i know that the Spam and Offensive flags are actually a "Nuke This" button. The dependency is way too big between what we are told and what it actually does

Comment: Is this a good candidate for an A/B test?

Comment: As someone who has been hammered with one of these flags for unintentionally offending people, I am heartily in favor of this.

Comment: This new wording is an improvement, but I don't think it solves the problem. I agree with OP that these options (spam, and rude or offensive) should be separated from the other options and clearly marked as a last-resort option. They're **big guns** but neither the current UI nor this proposal indicates that.

Comment: Your new description of "abusive" excludes gibberish. Please fix...

Comment: You could add some empty space between "rude" and other buttons to reduce (rare) accidental clicks.

Answer (score -42):

In my opinion, "offensive" flagging should be **removed** altogether. It should be hard to label something offensive<sup>1)</sup>. If a problem occur that requires immediately attention the "*in need of moderator intervention*" should be used (or spam when appropriate).

If *actually offended*<sup>1)</sup> the person would do the extra effort and contact SE through the public contact channel, hopefully itself creating enough obstacles to make a "offended" person cool down and think twice.

I know being offended is all the rave nowadays, however, being easily offended may seem more a [pretending to be offended](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325561/1693593) in many if not most cases, only serving as a reason for the person to self-grant an incentive to abuse the system for content (s)he doesn't like (very much how like censorship work); "I don't agree", "I don't like your opinion/statement/words" or even ["I think this is stupid"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325561/1693593), "I don't like this person" or "my feelings got (butt)hurt" - none a real neither good reason!

This way the system *itself* becomes a tool of abuse as ([1]:) there are absolutely no way to prove actual offensiveness in any shape or form. Period.

If not removed though, the tool tip should say something like, again in my opinion: "You're on the freakin' internet!" followed by either "grow some balls!" or "grow a spine!", or perhaps a more neutral "grow up!".

My 1 cent :]

Comment: the Hostility and anger that is implied by those suggestions for the new tool tip is way to much. I get the reasoning behind it, but that is in no way appropriate for any Stack Exchange site.  There are far better ways to go about it then insulting the person. If they are one of the "pretending to be offended" or easily offended in the first place, it will just escalate things

Comment: So you feel [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37623613/appending-to-a-string-in-bash-w-o-prefixing-extra-whitespace/37623668#37623668)(10K only link) doesn't need an offensive flag so we can nuke it?

Comment: @Ryan "Hostility and anger" hmm, interesting. In the old days we called this talking sense to someone.

Comment: @NathanOliver deleted? yes (moderator intervention), offensive? no (more a giggle, and childish)

Comment: The problem is talking sense into someone situational, a Case by case basis, not a One size fits all deal. You treat a child throwing a tantrum for being a brat differently than a guy who just lost a limb despite the fact both are screaming. In this case, you will get both, and everything inbetween, so having something that is situational and insulting is unacceptable. You cant talk like you are only speaking to the brat child when on the other side you could easily have the man missing a Limb. For a website, doing so guarantees no one is happy.

Comment: @Ryan I am pretty sure the guy who just lost his limb wouldn't type anything on SO

Comment: Well, if he uses Human.leg.cutoff() he could make a compelling code question regarding why its functionality was taken so literally and how to press control + z in real life. Point is, I hope your joking like I am.

Comment: @Ryan yes I am :)= in part anyways as there is a serious *underlying* message here. I do not expect it to be absorbed in general though..

Comment: This answer offends me! I'm going to flag this with a nuke.